# Eclipse Javadoc Editing a Pattern Isn't Saving

Tags: java, eclipse, coding-style

I'm using Eclipse Oxygen (4.7.2) on MacOS and I'm trying to edit the pattern for some specific Javadoc. Right now if I move my cursor over a class and hit <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> it formats the Javadoc as so:

```
/**
* @author MY_USER_NAME
*
*/
```

But in Preference/Java/Code Style/Code Templates/Comment 
the pattern has been edited to include other stuff, yet they don't appear in the auto-generated Javadoc. (I've tried restarting Eclipse after hitting apply and close to see if that was the problem).

Any reason as to why?
[image: ScreenShot of Problem]

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this issue with Eclipse Oxygen.2 (4.7.2) on Windows 10. Which Eclipse version do you have?

Comment: Eclipse 4.7.2, can you explain to me how you saved the pattern and use it? I think that may help me  to pinpoint my error

Comment: In your screenshot, all you have to do is press _Apply and Close_ and create a Javadoc comment for a class/interface/enum that does not yet have a Javadoc comment. But I assume you did exactly that. Due to the empty line between the comment and the class, try to change the code template _Files_ instead of _Types_.

Comment: I was wondering that too, so I changed all my templates to include some debugging line like "is this working", none of them show up if I hit CMD + OPTION + J.

Comment: Strange. Are you sure your workspace preferences will not be overwritten by project specific settings (in the dialog, see the link in the top right)?

Comment: Not to my knowledge, I've recently download Eclipse Oxygen (no prior downloads) I've haven't touched the Project Specific Settings.